# Get previous route/url in AuthGuard

Tags: angular, typescript

Sometimes a user might access my page without being logged in on the current device. For that case I have an `AuthGuard` which checks if a user is logged in. If not, it gets redirected to the `/login` page.

Now, sometimes I need the user to be moved to a particular page *after* it logged in. Also, query paramters need to be moved along like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  private previousUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _logger: NGXLogger
  ) {

    this._router.events
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.previousUrl = null;    
        if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
          this.previousUrl = event.url;
        }
      });
  }

  canActivate() {

    console.log('canActivate')
    if (AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this._logger.debug('User is logged in.');
      return true;
    }

    let loginParams = {};

    if (this.previousUrl) {

      const url = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.url;
      const queryParams = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;

      const paramsList = [];
      for (const k of Object.keys(queryParams)) {
        paramsList.push(`${k}=${queryParams[k]}`);
      }

      const paramsStr = paramsList.length ? `?${paramsList.join('=')}` : '';
      const enc = encodeURIComponent(`${this.previousUrl}${paramsStr}`);

      loginParams = {redirect: enc};
    }

    this._router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: loginParams});

    return false;
  }

  canActivateChild() {
    return this.canActivate();
  }    
}
```

for routes:

```
{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: './module/application/application.module#ApplicationModule',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```

Now, I didn't find another way to get my hands on the prevous URL. The problem with this solution is that `previousUrl` is not set at the time `canActivate()` gets executed which means `previousUrl` is always `undefined` at that point.

How can I get the previous URL before the `AuthGuard` gets control?

I already looked at

```
console.log(this._router.url);
console.log(this._activatedRoute.snapshot.url);
```

*before* I redirect to `/login`

but `_router.url` is *already `/login` and the `url` snapshot is just an empty list `[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the original URL to login component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url and return false
        this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

See here: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/08/angular-2-redirect-to-previous-url-after-login-with-auth-guard

Edit:

> If not, it gets redirected to the /login page.

This is where you would get the current page and use the guard to pass on as a parameter to login component